# How to center labels in simulator?

Tags: swift, xcode7-beta5

I am new to xcode and I'm still trying to figure out how the controller and simulator works.  I am using xcode beta 7.

If I try to center my text field and label in the controller, it looks shifted to the right in the simulator.  How do I get it to center in the simulator?
And, is there a view to preview what my screen will look like without constantly running the simulator?

And, how am I supposed to use the controller properly, if I don't know what the alignment is supposed to be under different formats?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use those Constraints:

- Horizontal Center in Container
- Vertical Center in Container.

[image]

Comment: How do I use it exactly?  If I want to center for iphone 6, what do I do?  I can't figure this out